# How to set iChat status from the command line?

Tags: command-line, ichat, messages, last.fm

I'm trying to sync my Last.FM last played track with my iChat status... right from the command line. I've come this far:

```
curl -s http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/1.0/user/Da3X/recenttracks.rss |
    grep -m 1 -E -e "         <title>(.*)</title>.*" |
    sed "s/.*<title>//" |
    sed "s/<\/title>//"
```

which results in the currently or last played track like

```
The Black Seeds – Cracks In Our Crown
```

Is there a way to forward this string as the iChat / Messages status now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it myself... format the output of `sed` as AppleScript and call `osascript`...

```
curl -s http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/1.0/user/Da3X/recenttracks.rss |
    grep -m 1 -E -e "         <title>(.*)</title>.*" |
    sed "s/.*<title>/tell application \"Messages\" to set the status message to \"♬  /" |
    sed "s/<\/title>/\"/" |
    sed "s/\&amp;/\&/" |
    osascript
```

That's it!

Comment: minor improvement - replaceing &amp; with & : http://pastebin.com/fAE4dnJk

Comment: Answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

This is waaaay too long to try and summarise into an answer here, but there is a really cool script that was written to do the same thing but with iTunes [here](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1636).

Should give you what you need :-)